# Android proguard enable with gigya sdk

Tags: android, gigya

I am facing issue related to gigya login popup dailog. When I am enabling proguard as making "minifyEnabled true" login popup is not showing.I have checked response.I am getting below mentioned response.

```
{  "errorMessage": "Permission denied",  "errorDetails": "Invalid namespace 'socialize' or method 'getUserInfo' or you do not have the required permissions to call it. ",  "statusCode": 403,  "errorCode": 403007,  "statusReason": "Forbidden",  "callId": "a8f696d6af194433a826893ea0c60b02",  "time": "2017-10-09T15:08:18.023Z"}
```

Same is working fine if proguard is not enabled.

Comment: @SardarKhan - where does the official documentation mention this? - also why is javascript tagged?

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding one of the following to your Proguard config file (this might be "proguard-rules.pro" or "proguard-rules.txt" from Finder).

```
-libraryjars libs/*name-of-gigya-sdk*.jar
```

or (depending upon your project settings)

```
-keep class com.gigya.** { *; }
```

Comment: Keeping everything in the library is indeed the way to go until https://github.com/SAP/gigya-android-sdk/issues/3 is fixed.