# Proguard problems with Gigya integration Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-proguard, android-facebook, gigya

I've had problems with proguard showing the **facebook login button**. It wasn't showing when an APK was executed running Proguard. Finally, I manage to solve it by adding the following lines in the **proguard-rules.pro** file:

*## Facebook specific rules ##

-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.facebook.**

IMO, they are too generic, Should I use another ones?

Comment: I haven't heard back from Dev yet, but maybe look at this in the meantime, it seems very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660558/android-proguard-enable-with-gigya-sdk